# Replace URL path in browser, not in request

Tags: javascript, tomcat, web, fiddler

I'm developing web application and its listening URL is:

```
localhost:8080/secret/index.jsp
```

But I need it to work on browser with

```
localhost:8080/public/index.jsp
```

I need to just hide the secret word from the browser address. e.g. localhost:8080/secret/* -> localhost:8080/public/*

I'm using tomcat webserver. Is there any way to achieve this on client or server side with any tools?

Comment: You can do it with `history.pushState` if it's supported

Comment: do you plan on having people browse to :8080 or do you plan on using a webserver (Apache, Nginx) to proxy traffic.  Then you would just set your proxy to point to localhost:8080/secret/ and they would just see whateveryounameyourdomain.com/index.jsp.  That would mean people don't have to add the port no. and handles that abstraction for you.  Might not strictly be what you are asking, but thats how I would handle it. Info can be found here on how to accomplish this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607922/apache-tomcat-proxypass-virtualhost-context-path

Comment: You do understand, I hope, that users will be able to see the "secret" using Fiddler or other tools? And that replaceState only works in HTML5-supporting browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Explosion Pills!

```
history.replaceState({}, 'Public title', '/public/index.jsp');
```

worked.